# Vertical Menu (+ Sub-Menu) stacks unnaturally

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm making an responsive menu which should be horizontal on desktop and align vertically on mobile.
While the Desktop-Version has no issues, the Mobile one behaves really strange.

[image: example image]

So this is the mobile menu. The 1st-Level Entries are in blue, 2nd-Level in gray. On the image you can only see two of the 2nd-Level entries even if there're 3 of them. Another issue is that these are at the very end of the menu, rather than under the 1st-Level entry.

Every element has

```
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

With that it should at the very least stack properly, which it doesn't. Since it's part of the framework I'm working on, the CSS-File is rather huge and may not be easy to read.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEPYYW

Comment: You should provide enough HTML & CSS to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Totally forgot to add the link. Added now, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

**This may not be the answer you're looking for but I hope it helps anyway...**

Personally, I would use the (now not so) new CSS Flexible Box Layout to achieve what you want much more easily, there's a great guide to it at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Essentially, what you'll want to do (among other options obviously) is have `flex-direction: column` on the desktop site and switch that to `row` on the mobile view. This simply switches the orientation of the menu from horizontal to vertical.

In my opinion this is the best (and most modern) way of doing this. However, it is worth noting that some would argue that browser support isn't as good as more traditional methods. This is true, but if you look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox, you'll see that in modern browsers it works fine.

I hope this is useful even though it's not a direct solution to your problem!

Comment: That's awesome. Didn't really think of using flex too much, but it looks really promising. I'll change it to use flex and give you an update if it worked.

Comment: Updated the system to use flex thanks to your answer. But sadly the issue is still there. Thanks for letting me know of what flex can do tho :)