# display json data dynamically from any api in table by adding data in table vertically or convert row data to column data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, angular

I want to switch rows to columns , please provide javascript or react js format . Thank you

```
            const dataArray = [
              { product: "Product 1", year: "2009", sales: "1212" },
              { product: "Product 2", year: "2009", sales: "522" },
              { product: "Product 3", year: "2010", sales: "1337" },
            ];
```

//App.js

```
    function App() {

      const renderOriginalTable = (data, index) => {
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{data.product}</td>
            <td>{data.year}</td>
            <td>{data.sales}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      };

      return (
        <div className="container">
          <h2>Original Table</h2>
          <table className="originalTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Sales</th>
              </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>{dataArray.map(renderOriginalTable)}</tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App
```

According to the code above, table will be as below :

```
   Product   | Year | Sales
   Product 1 | 2009 | 1212
   Product 2 | 2009 | 522
   Product 3 | 2010 | 1337
```

But I want the same data to be dispalyed as

```
 Product | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3
 Year    | 2009      | 2009      | 2010
 Sales   | 1212      | 522       | 1337
```

by converting rows into columns from the above mentioned jsan data.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be able to change the orientation just by using JavaScript. You have to restructure the table and use some CSS to change the orientation. First, remove the `thead` and move the `tr` with the `th` inside `tbody`:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Sales</th>
  </tr>
  {dataArray.map(renderOriginalTable)}
</tbody>
```

Then use CSS flexbox to change the table orientation:

```css
tbody {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: stretch;
}

tr {
  flex-basis: 33.33333333%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

th,
td {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Live example @[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-monad-vk4q8)

You can other CSS solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468762/change-orientation-to-vertical-table-rows-html-css).

Answer (score 1):

```
        <table className="originalTable">
       
          <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            {dataArray.map((item, index) => {
             <td>{item.product}</td>
             })}
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            {dataArray.map((item, index) => {
             <td>{item.year}</td>
             })}
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th>Sales</th>
          {dataArray.map((item, index) => {
             <td>{item.sales}</td>
             })}
          </tr>

       
       
      </table>
```

try something like this, this might work

Comment: this is also working fine , depends on the application method. we can use . Thank you